# How can I get bat to colorize *.log files and honor the escape codes in the log file itself

Tags: logback, batcat

I have .log files that were generated by a Java program using logback.  Some of the columns in the log file are colorized with logback.  The escape codes for the colors are embedded in the file.

When I view this file with an older version 0.6.0 of [bat](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat) the log file is displayed with all the original colors.  But, i just installed bat version 0.19.0 and now *.log files are displayed differently.  `bat --list-languages` shows that there is a language called log mapped to *.log.  What is this "log" language?  How do I change it to just show the raw file with its embedded colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a little more poking around, I found this seemed to work:

```
$ batcat --map-syntax "*.log:Plain Text" buildout.log
```

Apparently, "Plain Text" will generate output that is not as plain as `/usr/bin/cat`.  "Plain Text" will honor the embedded escape codes.